# Select input field from iframe - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need help with selecting an input field from iframe with jquery, the
iframe looks like this :

```
<iframe src="https://checkout.klarna.com" id="klarna-checkout-iframe" name="klarna-checkout-iframe" class="kloading" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 940px; width: 100%; transition: height 0.15s;"></iframe>
<input class="-test" type="text" name="challenge.postal_code" value="name">
<input class="-square" type="tel" name="challenge.postal_code" value="03434">
</iframe>
```

and I am using this jQuery code to get a input field :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframe = $('iframe').contents()find('input[type=tel]')
</script>
```

and now for testing the input field I use this jQuery for change style of it :

```
$(iframe).style.border = '1px solid #000000'
```

I have tried many things to make it work, but I still cannot select the iframe, is there somebody here that can help me?

Comment: there are quite a few errors in your code. you should open the console in your browser and that will give you some clues. For example you need to chain the jquery methods - `$('iframe').contents()find` won't work. You need to add a dot after `contents()` so it is  `$('iframe').contents().find()`

Comment: do you think that it is a cross domain problem?

Comment: Quite possibly, Have you tried with the updated code provided below? What does it say in the console with that code?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the below?

```
<iframe src="https://checkout.klarna.com" id="klarna-checkout-iframe" name="klarna-checkout-iframe" class="kloading" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 940px; width: 100%; transition: height 0.15s;">
    <input class="-test" type="text" name="challenge.postal_code" value="name">
    <input class="-square" type="tel" name="challenge.postal_code" value="03434">
</iframe>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe = $("#klarna-checkout-iframe").contents().find('input[type="tel"]');
    $(iframe).css("border","1px solid #000000"); 
</script>
```

Comment: @yapnop try it again, as the `iframe` is now closed at the correct point

Answer (score 0):

Here try this.

```
$('#iframe').each(function() {
   $('#MyDiv', this.contentWindow.document||this.contentDocument);
});
```

**Note:** Iframe contents are available only if they are on the same domain.

Comment: problem is here that they are not in same domain! so what can i do?

Comment: @yapnop Because of security issues, that is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Your `iframe` is closed early:

```
<iframe ...></iframe>
...           ^^^^^^
</iframe>
```

Remove the extraneous closing tag.

Comment: @yapnop combine that with the code I provided and it should work